# Change or Update the schema structure of mongodb using python

Tags: python, mongodb

so i have a file upload functionality. after uploading the excel file, then in my python code it will read the excel file

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_name, target_sheet)
```

next im gonna do this.

```
json = df.to_json(orient='records', date_format='iso', date_unit='s')
```

then im going to update / insert the data using mongodb.

```
MyMongoDB.db[my_collection].update(dataType, json, upsert=True)
```

the `dataType` contains the column Header of the table. when I print the `dataType` it will give me this

```
 { u`Total: u`number, u`Agent: u`string and so on..
```

my plan was to avoid the data types error of all field since im extracting data from excel. when I use that one line of code. it gives me this error.

```
TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type that inherits from collections.Mapping.
```

any help is appreciated. thanks community.

Comment: Well because you exported a "JSON String" and not a `instance of dict, bson.son.SON, ...`. MongoDB data is NOT JSON. It's just inserted as a `dict` as far as python is concerned.

Comment: if I did this. json = df.to_dict() now it gives me an error of documents must have string keys. what approach should I do

Comment: Well that's called another problem. But it also has another answer, and of course it's based on the error message you have already. You need to fix the dict output so the keys are not numeric.